# PHP - regexp to split URLs

Tags: php, regex

I have a text with "`a href`" and "`[link]`" links. I want to preg_split this text and have array where on [i] I can found links

Example:

```
My text <a href="www.example.com">text</a> this continues [link=http://www.second.com]link[/link]

=>

[0] My text
[1] <a href="www.example.com">text</a>
[2] this continues
[3] [link=http://www.second.com]link[/link]
```

How should I wrote my regexp?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions.  Use [the DOM module that comes with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).  Regular expressions are not always the tool to use, even if the problem involves text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(.+)(\<a.+\/a>)(.+)(\[link.+\/link])`

produces

```
Match groups:
1.  My text
2.  <a href="www.example.com">text</a>
3.  this continues
4.  [link=http://www.second.com]link[/link]
```

http://rubular.com/r/8PEUbDX9zr

Answer (score 0):

Something like this i guess. Assuming everything is on the same line..

```
/\<a\.*[link=(.*)\].*$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$text = 'My text <a href="www.example.com">text</a> this continues [link=http://www.second.com]link[/link]';


preg_match_all('/(?:href="|link=)(.*?)(?:"|\])/is', $text, $links);
// $links[1] = array('link', 'link', 'link'...)
$links = $links[1]; // $links = array('link'...)
?>
```

Should work :)

Comment: It returns only [0] => www.example.com

Comment: If I copy my example straight off and run it and var_dump $links I get     

    [0] => "www.example.com" 

    [1] => "http://www.second.com"

Sure you are using preg_match_all?

Comment: Strange.. If I copy & paste your example, I got only what I posted... and even your output is different from what I needed